# Angularfire2 child_changed equivalent

Tags: angular, angularfire2

How could I get only the modified child's value using angularfire2.
So with this:

```
this.af.database.list('/users').subscribe(x =>{
  //x is array of users
});
```

I get every child if only one child gets modified.

Although with this method I can get only the modified child's value it does not seem a proper way to do it:

```
this.af.database.list('/users')._ref.on('child_changed', c =>{
  console.log("child_changed ", c.val());
});
```

If I understood correctly angualrfire2 caches a branch and emmits all the values on any childevent so I have to filter out manually the modified child from the stream.

**EDIT:**

Because TypeScript compiler can complain about the private `_ref` tag it is better to use the embedded firebase instance to get a reference:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').on('child_changed', c =>{
      console.log("child_changed ", c.val());
    });
```

Maybe a `declare var firebase:any;` is needed outside your class definition.

Comment: I'm affraid there is no better solution than that I provided.
See:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/55
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/66

Comment: Thanks. Seeing the code for getting modified child value was helpful.